# Celery tasks with the same name

Tags: python, celery

I am implementing a file tree walking script that calls tasks based on the file extension or directory name.

My walking code looks like this:

```
from celery import Celery
import os


app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = 'path_walker',
    CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = 'topic',
)   

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/"):
    for filename in files:
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if ext:
            app.send_task("process", args=(os.path.join(root, filename),), routing_key="file" + ext)
    for dirname in dirs:
        app.send_task("process", args=(dirname,), routing_key="directory." + dirname)
```

You can see that I'm calling the same task (`process`) but with different `routing_key`s.

In my worker I have:

```
from celery import Celery
from kombu import Queue, Exchange
import uuid

app = Celery(broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

file_queue = Queue(str(uuid.uuid4()), routing_key="file.py")
dir_queue = Queue(str(uuid.uuid4()), routing_key="directory.tmp")

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE="path_walker",
    CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE="topic",
    CELERY_QUEUES=(
        dir_queue,
        file_queue,
    ),
)


@app.task(name="process", ignore_result=True, queue=dir_queue)
def process_dir(dir_name):
    print("Found a tmp dir: {}".format(dir_name))


@app.task(name="process", ignore_result=True, queue=file_queue)
def process_file(file_name):
    print("Found a python file: {}".format(file_name))
```

The above code creates two queues with different routing keys. The two tasks then bind to the individual queues but when I run the tree walker, only the second task (the `process_file` function) gets called.

Is it possible to have tasks with the same name but on different queues, run by the same worker. Or do I need to only have a single task per worker if I want to stick with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

It's not possible to have two tasks with the same name in a single celery app. I could split the above into two separate apps and run them with different workers, or provide unique names for the tasks.

The key bit of code in celery is here:

https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/8455b0c56797c22ba52abf59f4467ccc19eb9d20/celery/app/base.py